# Google Apps ScriptでのSyntaxErrorを解決したい

Tags: google-apps-script

GメールをLINEに自動転送したくて設定中です。
タイトルまでを転送する設定まではできたのですが、メール本文までLINEで見れるようにする所で躓いております。

資料によると33行目に以下のコードを挿入すれば良いという事ですが、挿入後保存する時にエラーが発生する状況です。
解決策をご教授いただければと思います。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
+ “\n\n[Message]\n”+ myMsgs[i].slice(-1)[0].getPlainBody();
```

**全体のコード:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: コードは画像ではなく文字のまま質問に貼り付けてください。

Answer (score 1):

> “\n\n[Message]\n”+ myMsgs[i].slice(-1)[0].getPlainBody();

もしこのコードそのままを使用しているなら、引用符が間違ってます。`“` (U+201C) ではなく `"` (U+0022) か `'` (U+0027) か ` (U+0060)を使ってください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。引用符変更で無事解決いたしました。